# for a marketplace slogan, is it better to use the word "discover" or the word "buy"?

Tags: marketing

In a small marketplace that allows people to buy products from different sellers ...if you have a slogan like:

```
discover awesome products from local sellers
```

or is it better to use:

```
buy awesome products from local sellers
```

?

I think discover is less aggressive, but buy lets people know right away that you can buy things on the website, not just discover them.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How about "Mindlessly Consume" ... it's got a ring to it!

Comment: Do an A/B test!

Answer (score 3):

***Discover* has a sense of finding something new**.  So if the action is largely linked to finding new and interesting options, then I would go with this.

***Buy* is a transactional word**, and indicates that you will go to get a product to purchase.  Use this if your user likely already knows what they will be buying and won't primarily be discovering new items.

> I *buy* toilet paper

but

> I *discover* new music

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the word "buy" isn't attractive.
People are more curious, they like discovering at first sight. They don't want to buy anything (unless it's proven that the product would efficiently change or enhance their life for the good, then they could run!)

Before buying a product, people are attracted then, if convinced, buy.

If the word "buy" is right away displayed, people will squeeze the product even if it's a good one.

Comment: there's an opposing argument that if they've arrived on the site with the intention to buy something, then they want the journey to purchase something labelled clearly with the word "buy".

Comment: @Racheet it's not as obvious as this. People can just get a look at a marketplace online with no intention to buy whatever but to pick up some new ideas... Using the word "buy" would make them -maybe unconsciously- feel 'compelled' to.

Comment: I do see what you're saying, but to me the primary thing is that  they've deliberately gone to an online marketplace, and so they've opted in to being in a space that's about buying things. I don't think it would be unexpected to for them to see messages about buying things. It's the same as if they've chosen to go to a shopping mall to get inspiration. In that case they'd be unlikely to be surprised that the messaging they see relates to buying things, since that's the expected messaging in that space.

Comment: @Racheet agreed. But unless attracting people by new sales or discounts coupons, it's IMHO unnecessary to remind them they're visiting a marketplace to 'buy'. People should 'feel' more free.

Comment: I think we just have different but equally legitimate opinions here. I think a marketplace which is nervous about talking its users in the language of buying and selling is also likely to be nervous about the clear labeling of things necessary for good information architecture. But I very definitely respect your opinion, it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's an argument that if they've arrived on the site with the intention to buy something, then they want the journey to purchase something labelled clearly with the word "buy".

On UX (rather than marketing) grounds I'd use "discover" on a lead generation site, and "buy" on a purchasing site.

If your site is a place where people expect to buy things, there's no shame in clearly labeling that's what it is. That actually makes life easier, and so more pleasant, for your users.

That being said, if you're uncomfortable with highlighting the purchase aspect, there are several neutral option between the two. For example "get". i.e. get awesome products from local sellers